# SQL Nearest Match Based on Predefined List

Tags: sql, search, text

I have a table of customers which has 1,000s of records. As part of a web application I'd like to be able to give the user a text box to enter a customers name in and for the app to then display some details.

Obviously this depends on two things: 1) The customer's name entered correctly on the database record and 2) The user entering the customer's name correctly in the search box.

What I'd like to do is have the user enter some text, the system then return the necessary data if there is a match or (more importantly), show a list of the nearest matches (ie from the customer list) for the user to select from if there is not an exact match.

So, using MS SQL 2005, is there an easy way of doing the latter?

Shaun.

Comment: Are the customernames mainly english ones? Or International?

Answer (score 1):

There are a matching algorithm [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) you can easly apply it to get the matching strings see [this](http://databases.about.com/od/development/l/aasoundex.htm) :

```
SELECT
  FirstName,
  SOUNDEX(FirstName) AS SoundTest,
  DIFFERENCE(FirstName, 'textentered') As DiffTest
FROM
  customerTable
```

this is only applied if the column is one word and there is another matching algorithm called [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) i think you should look at

Comment: Soundex is working perfectly with english names but not with international names since soundex is using "similar soundings" of the english language.

Comment: @user1011024 Google for "Levenshtein Distance SQL Server 2005", this is most probably what you're looking for according to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way could be

```
first look for the exact match
if found display
else query database again using LIKE operator 
(select name
 from table
 where name like '%nameEnteredByUser%')
display user, all the possible combinations
```

although there might be more sophosticated approaches depending upon ur requirements

Comment: I initially thought of using LIKE but this does not take into account typo errors. eg. If a customer has a name of Müller, a user could enter Muller, Mueller etcl., Neither of which would return any results using 'LIKE'.

Comment: yes, it doesnot, thats the simplest !! u can have a look at the solution proposed by MGA, soundex is a reasonable algo @user1011024